# Laravel request parameters

Tags: laravel, request

I'm trying to verify that Laravel is indeed posting my request parameters to a route, so I have a route in web php:

```
Route::get('/signup', "SignupController@index");
```

That route has a corresponding controller created for it in `/Http/Controllers`

```
class SignupController extends Controller
{
    //
    function index()
    {
        dd( $request->all() );
    }
}
```

However, when I visit `localhost:8000/signup?uid=id`, `$request->all()` *appears empty*. What am I doing wrong and how can I receive query parameters in Laravel?

P.S. I know that a signup page should use POST and will switch from GET to POST as soon as I have this working

Comment: @brombeer no dice

Comment: Don't forget to import Request. ```use Illuminate\Http\Request;```

Comment: your $request is an undeclared variable. did not trigger an exception because it's in the dd() method.

Comment: `public function index(Illuminate\Http\Request, $request)`

Answer (score 1):

you need the request to be injected in the method.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SignupController extends Controller
{
    //
    function index(Request $request)
    {
        dd( $request->all() );
    }
}
```

Or use the helper

```
class SignupController extends Controller
{
    //
    function index()
    {
        dd( request()->all() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to retrieve query params is

```
  public function index(Request $request)
        {
    if( $request->has('uid') ) {
        $request->query('uid');
    
    }
}
```

or using the helper function if you don't have access to $request

```
public function index()
    {    request()->query('uid');
        dd(request()->all());
    }
```